# Sort QVector of pointers to custom objects

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, pointers, qvector

**My Question:**

What is the best way to assign numbers to each `Camera` in a `QVector<Camera*>` where the following specifications should apply:

- The unsorted `QVector` should keep its order
- The `int number` of each `Camera` should be assigned depending on its `QString macAddress`
- The `int number` should start with `0` for the "lowest" macAddress (`QString::operator<`)

---

**Sources:**

```
class Camera {
    int number;
    QString macAddress;
}
```

---

**Current solution:**

My curent solution is to:

- Implement `Camera::operator<`

  ```
  bool Camera::operator<(const Camera &cam) const {
      return(this->macAddress < cam.macAddress);
  }
  ```
- Implement a compare struct

  ```
  struct CameraCompare {
      bool operator()(const Camera *a, const Camera *b) {
          return(*a < *b);
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a temporary QVector of pointers to the same Camera-objects and then using `std::sort` on the temporary vector and assigning the numbers like the following:

  ```
  QVector<Camera*> tempVector;
  for(quint8 i = 0; i < cameras->size(); i++) {
      Camera *temp = (*cameras)[i];
      tempVector.append(temp);
  }
  std::sort(tempVector.begin(), tempVector.end(), CameraCompare());
  for(quint8 i = 0; i < tempVector.size(); i++) {
      tempVector[i]->setNumber(i); // Edited
  }
  ```

---

Edit: My question now is: Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what the best way is. But the reason why your numbering doesn't work could be because of the last line "cameras->at(i)->setNumber(i);"
I think it should be "tempVector[i]->setNumber(i);"
And since you are working with pointer it should update the correct camera object in cameras

Comment: One approach would be to implement an adapter iterator that would wrap the camera numbers but and return a wrapper type convertible to int that wraps a pointer to element, but comparing the mac addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution. It sorts the vector fine. But it seems there's something wrong here:

```
for(quint8 i = 0; i < tempVector.size(); i++) {
    cameras->at(i)->setNumber(i);
}
```

This code sets the `number` of each camera, the index of it in the *original* vector NOT the sorted vector. I think it should be replaced with:

```
for(quint8 i = 0; i < tempVector.size(); i++) {
    int number = tempVector.indexOf(cameras.at(i));
    cameras->at(i)->setNumber(number);
}
```

Comment: Yes it did. But isn't this tempVector a quite ugly solution tho? Do you have any ideas on how to solve the problem any better?

Comment: @ChristianB You can use `QMap`. It's automatically sorted based on its keys. If you consider `macAddress` as the key of each camera, you can simply use this container.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that yet!